# Most important journals in data mining/ML, NLP and IR?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, natural-language, information-retrieval, references

Can you please provide with me with the names of the most important journals in data mining, machine learning, natural language processing and information retrieval?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the must-read papers on data mining and machine learning?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81365/what-are-the-must-read-papers-on-data-mining-and-machine-learning)

Comment: @NickStauner how is this a duplicate? "Which journal's are important" is a very different question than "what papers are must-read."

Comment: Yup, good point! Implies an interesting meta-question: how much duplicity is too much? There is [some discussion of duplicate flagging issues on the meta-site](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/q/1719/32036) already. I went over to upvote it just now, as I agree this issue comes up a lot and sometimes get over-moderated. My flag was declined here though, and in retrospect, I think that was the right call. Thanks for your point!

Answer (score 2):

For machine learning this would include the following, with no specific ordering:

- [Journal of Machine Learning Research](http://jmlr.org/)
- [IEEE Transactions on Pattern Analysis and Machine Intelligence](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/RecentIssue.jsp?punumber=34)
- [IEEE Transactions on Neural Networks and Learning Systems](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/RecentIssue.jsp?punumber=5962385)
- [Neural Computation](http://www.mitpressjournals.org/loi/neco)
- [Neurocomputing](http://www.journals.elsevier.com/neurocomputing/)

Also check out things published at big conferences like KDD and NIPS.

Comment: The problem with IEEE papers is that one can't access them. I'm in a German university and we don't have access to papers published by IEEE

Comment: @guckogucko IEEE journals are still very important in the domain, despite having a paywall.

Answer (score 1):

I flagged this question as a duplicate of your other question that's now on hold, but since this one isn't on hold yet too, I'm posting this answer as a redirect to the two upvoted answers on the duplicate. @DikranMarsupial provided [one answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/81382/32036), and @samthebest provided [another](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/81381/32036). You may also want to refer to [another question specifically about machine learning journals](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/29452/32036) that also resembles your question quite a lot.

Comment: As per my (non-automatically-generated) comment on the OP, I agree with the decision to decline my flag on this question. The other question was put on hold as too broad (not my opinion), and this question is somewhat less broad, so I hope it won't be put on hold at all.